# Cannot format 8GB USB Drive Partition

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, file-management, disk-management

So, I have a 8GB USB thumbrive I am trying to format so I can use all 8 (or 7.27 to be exact) GB in a single partition.   The drive already has a 943 MB partition, which I figured I could extend to use the full 7.27 GB but this does not seem to be the case

[image: New Volume Right Click]

As you can see, the Extend volume option is greyed out.

Also notice the Delete volume is greyed out..

If I right click on the 6.35 GB volume, which is currently unallocated I get the following
[image: unallocated volume]

All of the options are greyed out on the Unallocated volume!

What tool can I use to remove the existing partition and create a new partition that uses the entire 7.27 GB in a single volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will not let you partition removeable storage devices. You must delete all of the partitions and make a new, full size one outside of Windows. I recommend the GParted Live CD.

Comment: That's not entirely true; it will not let you create more than a single partition on removable storage devices. And the the 'Disk Management' GUI will not let you delete partitions from removable storage to "prevent inadvertent data loss".

Answer (score 36):

Have you tried using [diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)?

Specifically, in a `cmd.exe` window, running the following commands will erase and reformat your USB drive:

```
> diskpart.exe
    list disk                 'This will list your disk drives, 
                              ' note the number of your USB drive
    select disk #             'Replace # here with the number from above
    clean                     'This removes all partitions
    create partition primary
    select partition 1
    active
    format fs=NTFS QUICK
    assign                    'This assigns it a drive letter
    exit
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a USB drive that had been partitioned as a boot drive, but I needed to use it for normal storage again. I also could not re-partition/format using Disk Management (Start->Run->compmgmt.msc->Storage->Disk Management); it was greyed out for me too. Using **DISKPART** got me most of the way. Here's what I did:

1. **Click Start button then typed Command Prompt and right clicked and selected "Run as administrator".** The Command Prompt (a.k.a DOS prompt for us old people) will appear.
2. **Type in diskpart.exe**. You'll notice that you loose the **"c:\"** and you just see **"DISKPART>"** because this is an actual command line program. All the commands available in **DISKPART** can be viewed by typing in **help**
3. **list disk** will list all the disks currently on your system, even ones that are not mounted. They'll show up as "Disk 1", "Disk 2" etc, with corresponding sizes. If you have a few different USB drives inserted with similar sizes, I suggest you only leave in the one you want to change, so you KNOW which Disk to choose on the next step.
4. **select disk #** in my simple scenario, it was **"select disk 1"** You should see **"Disk 1 is now the selected disk."**. Disk 0 will most likely be your C Drive. Be SURE you've selected the disk you want to repartition.
5. **clean** This will delete all the partitions.

For me that's all I needed. I was able to use create a partition and reformat after that using **Disk Management**, although I had to NOT use the "Quick Format" option.